# Padding numbers in filename with 0's

Tags: batch-file

I have some files whose names are like

```
Image 1.jpg
Image 2.jpg
Image 10.jpg
Image 11.jpg
Image 20.jpg
```

They are numbered in the exact order that I want them to appear, but windows takes them in this order when I do a `dir`

```
Image 1.jpg
Image 10.jpg
Image 11.jpg
Image 2.jpg
Image 20.jpg
```

If these were supposed to be frames in an animation, your animation would basically come out wrong.

I would like to pad the numbers with 0's. The format of the strings are always the same

```
PREFIX NUMBER.EXT
```

How can I pad the filenames so that I will get

```
Image 0001.jpg
Image 0002.jpg
Image 0010.jpg
Image 0011.jpg
Image 0020.jpg
```

Here is what I have done so far

```
echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem note the extra space at the end of "Image "
set prefix=Image 
for %%F in (*.jpg) do (
  set a=%%F
  rem // strip the prefix
  set a=!a:%prefix%=!
  echo !a!
)
```

This removes the prefix. I would then pad the resulting filename with leading characters 0's and then rename the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing that prefix replacement, you could isolate the number like this: (remove `echo` to enable the rename command)

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%A in (*.jpg) do (
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=. " %%F in ("%%A") do (
       set /a a=%%G
       set zeros=
       if !a! LSS 1000 set zeros=0
       if !a! LSS 100 set zeros=00
       if !a! LSS 10 set zeros=000
       set "name=%%F !zeros!!a!.%%H"
       echo ren "%%A" "!name!"
    )
)

endlocal
```

Using `set /a` does a numeric conversion, then you can use the extension comparator `LSS` to compare the number and create the relevant padding, and finally reassemble the filename using its tokens.  This particular snippet isn't generic - it only works if your prefix has no spaces or dots, and the name only has three main tokens.  But you get the idea.

Comment: The loop syntax generated an error, I added an extra loop and a rename command.  Nice technique.

Comment: Cheers for that.  Admittedly I just tested it on a single string, rather than creating files, then replaced the string with a glob for the answer without checking it =)